# Need Gmail emails to be filtered out if it contains X, *unless* it contains Y

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Need Gmail emails to be filtered out if it contains one phrase, *unless* it also contains another thing.

For example, if the email is titled just "How Are You?", I do not want it to show.  But if it is titled "Re: How Are You?", I would like for it to show.

Is this kind of EXCEPT WHEN or UNLESS operation supported?

Answer (score 1):

### Use Quotes

Per your use case simply use quotes around the search terms.

**"Re: How Are You?"** (*alternatively* "Re How Are You") will not return **"How Are You"** unless the phrase is also preceded by **"Re"**.

No need for any exceptions.